# Как удалить последовательные повторы слова в строке с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, функции

Есть следующий текст:

```
text = 'Идет идет  медведь медведь, встретил  белку Белку и! упал  упал упал!'
```

в нем могут попадаться мусорные пробелы и знаки препинания.
Мне необходимо создать функцию, которая удалить последовательные повторы слова в строке, по логике, на выходи должно получиться:

```
'идет медведь встретил белку и упал'
```

Пока функция выглядит так:

1) пользуюсь `lower`, так как не понимаю как верно указать флаг `re.I` в основной регулярке ниже.

2) избавляюсь от лишних пробелов.

3) основная регулярка, чтобы избавиться от повторов (ПРОПУЩЕНО)

```
def del_repeats(text):
    new_text = text.lower()
    new_text = re.sub(r'\s+',' ', new_text)

    return new_text
```

Попробовал множество вариантов решения, упростил входящую строку, чтобы приблизить задачу к реальной, но не нахожу решения. Предыдущие пути решения можно смотреть [тут](https://github.com/sqrt495/PYDA-6_HW/blob/master/6/PYDA-6_HW-6.ipynb), если это интересно.

По условию решать задачу необходимо с помощью регулярных выражений. То есть использование `lower` — жульничество.

Comment: Почему выходные данные в нижнем регистре? Спрашиваю потому, что слово `идет` в нижнем регистре стоит после аналогичного в верхнем, а слово `белку` наоборот. В этом заложена какая-то логика? И насчёт знаков препинания, их просто нужно удалить?

Comment: @nomnoms12 в регистрах нет специальной логики. изначально я хотел оставить знак в конце строки, но мое задание не предполагает этого, поэтому отказался от идеи. искать идеальное решение здесь нет нужды - это учебная задача без конкретного прикладного значения. если видите альтернативные изящные пути решения, буду благодарен!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте

```
import re
s = "Идет идет  медведь медведь, встретил  белку Белку и! упал  упал упал!"
print( re.sub(r'\b([^\W\d_]+)(\s+\1)+\b', r'\1', re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', s).strip(), flags=re.I) )
# => Идет медведь встретил белку и упал
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/UIHIcE)

**Подробности**

- `re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', s).strip()` - заменяет 1 и более символов, отличных от букв, цифр и знаков подчёркивания, на один пробел, `.strip()` удалит пробелы в начале и конце строки
- `re.sub(r'\b([^\W\d_]+)(\s+\1)+\b', r'\1', ..., flags=re.I)`:

  - `\b([^\W\d_]+)(\s+\1)+\b` - находит и захватывает в подмаску №1 слово (последовательность 1 и более букв в границах слова), после которого следует 1 и более повторов 1+ пробельных символов и такое же слово (`\1` - обратная ссылка на значение подмаски №1), за которыми следует граница слова
  - `r'\1'` - заменяет найденное совпадение единичным экземпляром найденного слова (значение подмаски №1)
  - `flags=re.I` - включает регистронезависимый поиск текста

Answer (score 2):

Есть намного более простой способ:

```
def replace_doubles(some_string):
    pattern = r'(\w+)(\s+\1)+'
    return re.sub(pattern, r'\1', some_string)
```

Здесь я использовал такую последовательность: вначале ставим одно слово, делаем его группой, затем ставим вторую группу (любое число пробелов + то же самое слово/первая группа), повторенное 1 или более раз. Для большинства случаев более чем релевантно.