# Как удалить ненужный текст и сохранить медиа в сообщении Граббер каналов

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Имеется код:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from config import DESTINATION, API_ID, API_HASH, SESSION, CHATS, KEY_WORDS


client = TelegramClient(SESSION, API_ID, API_HASH)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Программа запущена...")

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=CHATS))
    async def new_order(event):
        try:
            print('Найдена новая новость...')
            contain_key_word = False

            for key_word in KEY_WORDS:
                if key_word in event.message.message:
                    contain_key_word = True

            if contain_key_word:
                await client.send_message(DESTINATION, event.message)

        except Exception as ex:
            print(f'Exception: {ex}')
            


    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Как удалить не нужный текст в больших количествах. Ссылки, названия канала, подписаться и так далее. При этом сохранить нужный текст и медиа.
С примером пожалуйста. Так как начинаю только.

Спасибо: [tomato-magnet-regulato](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/481134/tomato-magnet-regulato) и [gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red)

Получилось таким способом:

```
...
def clear_message(text):
return re.sub('Подпишись|https://|и тд', '', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

...

if contain_key_word:
                event.message.message = clear_message(event.message.message)
                await client.send_message(DESTINATION, event.message)
...
```

Comment: Вам нужны регулярные выражения

Comment: Можно пример с участием моего кода?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1045815/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd

Comment: @Daff, а зачем вы удалили свой прошлый вопрос, где я оставлял ответ с примером удаления текста регуляркой? :) Все-таки, я потратил на него время и силы, а вы это обесценили, не надо так делать :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1427210/

Comment: @gil9red, Извините. Я не тот вопрос удалил, а восстановить не смог. Огромная благодарность вам в решении вопроса. Теперь работает всё как надо)

Comment: @Daff, ладно, проехали :)